# Do sequencial animations in html using anime.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, anime.js

I'm using anime.js to create a couple of simple animations but I'm struggling to make it work.
The goal is to enable the user to roll a couple of dice. The dice starts in the middle of the screen and, when clicking a button, it should go down the screen until it disappears. Then it should appear again from the top of the screen (already with a new face), but this time it should come rolling.
I'm trying to do it with two, sequencial, animations. In the middle it should draw the new value.

Here is the html:

```
       <div class="outerDice" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 15;">
      <div class="dice" style="position: absolute; overflow: visible; z-index: 15; top:325px; left: 171px; width: 133px; height: 133px;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none; z-index: 4;">
          <div id="dice1" style="position: absolute;  background-image: url(images/plain_dice.png); background-size: 100% 100%; opacity: 1; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline; border-style: none; overflow: visible; z-index: 4; width: 133px; height: 133px;">
            <img src="images/story_dice33.png " height="125" width="125">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; top: 310px; left: 119px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2;">
        <img class="shadow" src="images/shadow.png" height="240px" width="240px" style="z-index: 4; display: inline; opacity: 0.5; position: absolute; overflow: visible;">
      </div>
    </div>

<button onclick="move();" style="z-index: 9999; position: absolute;  top: 0; left: 0px;" >CLICK ME</button>
```

And here the javascript:

```
function move(obj){
       
      var rollDice = anime({
              targets: ['.dice', '.shadow'],
              translateY: ["-500px", "0px"],
              duration: 1000,
              loop: false,
              autoplay: false,
              rotate: '1turn',
              easing: 'linear'
            });
      var dcount = 0, scount = 0;
      var drop = anime({
         targets: ['.dice', '.shadow'],
         translateY: ["0px", "100vh"],
         easing: 'easeInBack',
         duration: 2000,
         loop: false,
         autoplay: false,
         delay: function(el, i, l) {
          if(el.classList.contains("dice"))
            return ++dcount*100;
          if(el.classList.contains("shadow"))
            return ++scount*100;

            return i * 100;
          },
          complete: function(anim) {
            roll(document);
            rollDice.restart();
          }
       });
       drop.restart();
}
```

The funny thing is that, the first time I click the button, it works exactly as expected.
From there on, it works EXCEPT that the dice doesn't roll when coming back in...
I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a lot more search, I found the solution here: https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/380

The problem is that the first time the animation is run, it goes from 0turn to 1turn.
The second time the element is already in 1turn so it will not change anything.
The solution is to force to go from 0turn to 1turn always:

```
rotate: ['0turn', '1turn']
```